# Activity não abre

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Bom, criei duas Activity's quando eu clicasse no botao da primeira ele deveria abrir a segunda com informações recebidas da primeira. Mas não é isso que acontece, onde errei?

```
 using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
//Atividade Principal
namespace TabelaPeriodica
{
    [Activity (Label = "TabelaPeriodica", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            EditText edt = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.edtsmb);
            Button bttn = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.env);


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(edt.Text))
            {
                bttn.Click += delegate {
                    var ress = new Intent (this, typeof(Result));
                    ress.PutExtra ("simbol", edt.Text);
                    StartActivity (ress);
                };


            }


        }

    }
}
```

Segunda Activity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace TabelaPeriodica
{
    [Activity (Label = "Result")]           
    public class Result : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Result);

            TextView sm = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tsimb);

            sm.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("simbol") ?? "Erro";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o log da aplicação para nos ajudar. Você declarou a segunda Activity no manifest da aplicação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja que no `OnCreate` da sua `MainActivity` você nunca está adicionando o event handler do click do botão

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(edt.Text))
{
    bttn.Click += delegate {
        var ress = new Intent (this, typeof(Result));
        ress.PutExtra ("simbol", edt.Text);
        StartActivity (ress);
    };
}
```

O `OnCreate`, como o próprio nome já diz só é chamado quando a activity é criada, e quando ela for criada o `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(edt.Text))` vai sempre retornar false.

Você precisa mudar esta verificação, se só deve mostrar a segunda activity quando o usuário informar um valor então o `if` deve ficar dentro desta delegate, algo do tipo

```
bttn.Click += delegate {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(edt.Text))
    {
        var ress = new Intent (this, typeof(Result));
        ress.PutExtra ("simbol", edt.Text);
        StartActivity (ress);
    }
};
```